# Is a paper-action-dialog supposed to automatically center and scroll with dart-polymer?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to launch a modal dialog using PaperActionDialog in Dart and the dialog never centers and doesn't scroll if the content is longer than the window. Is it supposed to automatically? All the polymer-only examples I come across seem to. Do I have to style it somehow? Here's the code I'm using:

```
PaperActionDialog m = new PaperActionDialog();
m.setAttribute("role", "dialog");
m.setAttribute("backdrop", "true");
m.autoCloseDisabled=true;
PaperButton closeButton = new PaperButton();
closeButton.text="Close";
closeButton.raised = true;
closeButton.setAttribute("primary", "true");
closeButton.setAttribute("dismissive", "true");
m.children.add(closeButton);
m.heading="History";
m.open();
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `m.notifyResize();` (before or after `open()`)?

Comment: I just did, but same thing. Am I also supposed to add the dialog manually to the DOM somewhere or just let .open() place it there?

Comment: Usually it centers itself. You could try to add it statically and just change the content at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I did try the code above with an empty project and simple polymer element. Same thing, not centered. Bug report worthy? I haven't submitted one before... Thanks again.

Comment: Got the suggestion you made to work however now I've got a new issue. If I use querySelector to grab the PaperActionDialog at runtime from the DOM then instantiate a PolymerElement into the modal dialog's content, for some reason it calls the PolymerElement's attached() but then when it finally renders the dialog it calls detached() then attached() again. Is this because the PaperActionDialog is pushing the content to a shadow DOM when rendering?